# Is the Panasonic GH5's sensor likely to get damaged while in my bag?

Tags: sensor, equipment-damage

The Panasonic GH5's sensor is suspended in a magnetic field when in use, allowing it to move on 5-axis to stabilise the image.

However when not in use it is completely loose and flops around in its space (it can move around by a good 3-4mm in all directions) and it can clearly be heard and felt knocking around, presumably it has some sort of rubber buffers around it.

However in the long term, being carried in a camera bag, rucksack, handbag, neck-strap etc etc... Is it likely to suffer any actual physical damage? Is the flexible cable to it likely to degrade in time?

I am fully aware that they are built like this, and have of course been thoroughly tested, but sometimes there are unforeseen issues later in the life of products.

Comment: I can see a similarity, but its not really the same question, I am concerned with long term durability, I'm not asking "is this normal"

Comment: How can a question about long-term durability be answered regarding a recently introduced product?

Comment: The distinction you make is fairly fine. I suppose it be distinguishing enough. However, similar to Michael's point, all of your questions (including the question in the title) ask about the _likelihood_ of failure. Lacking MTBF statistics (which manufacturers are loathe to answer outside of special cases, or lawsuits, etc.), I'm not sure that _likelihood of damage/failure/degradation_ is answerable, other than speculation or opinion.